# How to delete scheduled task from command line without confirmation? (schtasks delete)

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, scheduled-task, batch-file

I can create a task from command line like this:

```
schtasks /create /tn SomeTask /tr "do.bat arg1 arg2" /sc ONCE /st 00:00:00 /sd 01/01/1991
```

and now I need to delete it. However the command needs to be confirmed and I don't know how to do that from BATCH file (bat/cmd).

```
C:\> schtasks /delete /tn ContextSwitchTask
WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "ContextSwitchTask" (Y/N)?

C:\> echo Y | schtasks /delete /tn ContextSwitchTask
WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "ContextSwitchTask" (Y/N)? Y
ERROR: Invalid input.
Type "SCHTASKS /DELETE /?" for usage.
```

**Question: How to delete scheduled task and force yes?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
C:\> schtasks /delete /tn ContextSwitchTask /f
```

Comment: Doesn't exist on XP, 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx